# How to use proguard in Appcelerator?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, proguard

I am trying to add proguard to Titanium project.

Proguard file is [here](https://github.com/pcpappc/referencecode/blob/master/proguard.cfg)

But getting an error in compiling the build.

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to run ProGuard
[ERROR] :  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  * What went wrong:
[ERROR] :  Execution failed for task ':proguard'.
[ERROR] :  > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Comment: `java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.`. Check the `above warnings`

Comment: I am unable to know what is causing io exception, therefore, cannot solve it

Comment: neither we can. We can't hack into your PC to see the `above warnings`